# How do I make the jquery dialog work with the themeroller themes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I am trying out the dialog from jquery UI. All the online [demos](http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/ui/demos/functional/#ui.dialog) use flora.css.
I can't get the dialog to display correctly with the css file generated by the [themeroller](http://ui.jquery.com/themeroller) application.
Am I missing something? Should these things work out of the box?

Update: Thanks Brock. When I cleaned up my code to make a sample, I realized that the HTML in *demo.html* (that comes with the themeroller.zip) is a little too verbose.
All I needed to do was give the dialog div the attribute `class="ui-dialog"` like this:

```html
<div id="SERVICE03_DLG" class="ui-dialog">please enter something<br><br>
<label for="something">somthing:</label>&nbsp;<input name="something" id="something" type="text" maxlength="20" size="24">
</div>
```

I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The solution was found in [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600/a-problem-with-the-jquery-dialog-when-using-the-themeroller-css) I posted:

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you have the classes different.

```html
<div id="SERVICE03_DLG" class="flora"> (flora)
<div id="SERVICE03_DLG" class="ui-dialog"> (custom)
```

Even with the flora theme, you would still use the `ui-dialog` class to define it as a dialog.

I've done modals before and I've never even defined a class in the tag. jQueryUI should take care of that for you.

Try getting rid of the class attribute or using the `ui-dialog` class.