# jQuery.dialog doesn't generate themeroller classes?

Tags: jquery, css, dialog

[JSBin sample](http://jsbin.com/edeve)

Get at that with Firebug and you'll notice something about the classes of the generated dialog - ui-widget and/or ui-state are completely absent, but those are the classes that ThemeRoller uses to color UI elements!

Is there some sort of ThemeRoller-compliant dialog generator, or even a script to hack the right display classes into a dialog after the fact?

Or, since I'm not intending to let my users edit their own themes, do I just have to do the bit of CSS hackery that the jQuery people apparently did [for their demos](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog), putting color information into ui.dialog.css?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600/a-problem-with-the-jquery-dialog-when-using-the-themeroller-css#177894) to another question.  It seems that the filament group made their own version of the standard jQuery dialogs specific to jQuery UI for use with themeroller, and the "standard" jQuery.dialog won't work.

Comment: Several months ago, yeah. But I thought that since then someone might have done work on combining Themeroller UIs and generated dialogs, and be willing to share.